# ROW number over a group with ordering. Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
 LotNumber  Device  MeasureDate RowNumber 
 LotA       DevA    10/1/15 0:00    1 
 LotA       DevA    10/1/15 1:00    1 
 LotA       DevB    10/1/15 2:00    2 
 LotB       DevA    10/1/15 3:00    3 
 LotB       DevA    10/1/15 4:00    3 
 LotA       DevA    10/1/15 5:00    4
```

I want to generate the RowNumber column based on group of LotNumber and Device.As long as the lot and device is the same, the rownumber will be the same. The order is by measuredate.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to give them rownumber based on lotnumber and device but according to the data youve posted its already in there. Is the data posted your expected output or what? can you please explain more what you are trying to do? And please post what have you done so far. Thanks

Comment: The Rownumber is my desired output, its what I need to generate.

Comment: have you tried any answer below.one of those answers should be working, i assume.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the `LAG` analytic function in an inline view, followed by a cumulative sum to only sum when the values differ from the previous row.

```
select lot_number,
       device,
       measure_date
       sum(case when last_lot_number = lot_number and last_device = device
                then 0
                else 1 end) over (order by measure_date) as row_number
  from (select lot_number,
               device,
               measure_date,
               lag(lot_number) over(order by measure_date) as last_lot_number,
               lag(device) over(order by measure_date) as last_device
          from your_table)
order by measure_date
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c4d4/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate rownumbers the same as what is displayed. You can try this

```
SELECT Lotnumber, 
       Device, 
       MeasureDate, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MEASURE DATE ) AS RowNumber 
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This is not giving the desired output. The rownumber becomes a rownumber for each row 1-6.

Comment: I think Balakumar's answer is right, you just have to add order by measuredate at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Dense_rank to get desired output.
create table device (lotnumber varchar2(5), device varchar2(5), measuredate date);
insert into device values ('LotA','DevA', sysdate);
insert into device values ('LotA','DevA', sysdate);
insert into device values ('LotA','DevB', sysdate);
insert into device values ('LotB','DevA', sysdate);
insert into device values ('LotB','DevA', sysdate);
insert into device values ('LotA','DevA', sysdate);

Use below query to get desired output.
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DEVICE.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LOTNUMBER, DEVICE) RM FROM DEVICE) ;
```

Comment: This is not giving the desired output. The measuredate is not being taken into account in ordering the rank.

Comment: try adding order by measuredate

Comment: select
lotnumber,
device,
measuredate,
dense_rank() over ( order by rk ) as seq
from
(
select
x.*,
last_value(r ignore nulls) over ( order by measuredate ) as rk
from
(
select
d.*,
case
when lotnumber != lag(lotnumber) over ( order by measuredate ) or
device    != lag(device) over ( order by measuredate )    or
row_number() over ( order by measuredate ) = 1
then
row_number() over ( order by measuredate )
end as r
from device d
) x
)
order by 3;
Try this query..